# Ionisation of a gas - from gas to plasma

Tags: mass-spectrometry

Is it possible to ionise a gas such as Carbon Dioxide? If you continue to heat up a gas eventually the electrons from the gaseous atoms are stripped away and those e- gain energy (endothermic reaction) to become a plasma. A plasma is a sea of gaesous cations and electrons that are not too far apart from each other (unlike a gas).

Having done some research, it is certainly possible:

http://www.dynamicscience.com.au/tester/solutions1/chemistry/isotopes/isotopes4.htm

https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRev.36.472

How do I represent this change from gas to plasma using an equation?

CO2 (g) -> X+ (g) + Xe-

Ionisation of Carbon and Oxide ion:

C (s) -> C+ (g) + e-

O2^2- (g) -> O2- (g) + e-

Related key terms: ionisation, recombination

Comment: Plasmas are generated by electrical means (using radiofrequency current) rather than by heating to temperature extremes. Decomposition of CO2  by microwaves plasma was recently published in Nature. They list all the possible reactions and report the species observed. https://www.nature.com/articles/srep18436

Comment: @M. Farooq Thanks for the link! are you saying that gases can’t be ionised through photo radiation/ionisation ? Thats why I don’t understand this sweeping statement: “plasmas are generated by electronic means rather than...” Because isn’t the state transition from a gas to plasma also called ionisation and the reverse process plasma to gas, recombination?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, ionization is a very broad term. It can be achieved by anything (radiation, heat, inductive coupling of radiofrequency current etc.). But an ionized gas is not necessarily a plasma however the plasma starts from the ionization process. It has to be sustained by an external energy source. See how it is defined by IUPAC "A gas which is at least partly ionized and contains particles of various types, viz. electrons, atoms, ions and molecules. The plasma as a whole is electrically neutral."

Comment: Carbon and oxygen are on the series of nuclear reactions that happen in stars. A big enough ball of carbon dioxide gas would collapse under its own gravity to create a thermonuclear reaction which would create a plasma. Since the temperature would vary in the depth of the gas various species would be present at the various depths.

Comment: @ M.Farooq - The paper you provided a link to was published in [Scientific Reports](https://www.nature.com/content/scirep-facts/index.html?utm_source=Nature_website&utm_medium=Website_links&utm_content=AngWan-Nature-Scientific_Reports-Multidisciplinary-Global&utm_campaign=SCIREP_AWA_scirep_facts_website), an open access journal from the Nature Research group that also publishes Nature.